# How to define a custom layer in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, machine-learning-model, pytorch, custom-layer

I am new to PyTorch and seeking your help regarding a problem I have. I need to add a costume layer to a NN in training phase. Please see the figure which shows a simple DNN with the custom layer. NN is trying to solve a regression problem.

Let's consider the simplest case, $f_1(input)=f_2(input)=f_3(input)=sin(a\times input)$, where $a$ is constant. How can I handle such an NN in PyTorch.

Also, can we treat $a$ as a trainable parameter as well if we don't assume it as a predefined constant?

I appreciate any hint or similar example using PyTorch.

[image]